# Is there any way to run mpi on windows OS?

Tags: windows, mpi

I have msys64 installed, it's running openmp perfectly, however I also want to run mpi command there, it is not working. Please how can I configure my windows 10 os to run mpi too?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and easiest way is using linux or Mac, which you can install those os by virtual machines in your system.

But If you want to use Windows, for compiling the parallel code with msmpi you can download and use msmpisdk.msi

The created path is most of the time something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI and you could find include and library directories there.

Comment: please is there really any problem with using the Microsoft mpi? Secondly when installed, what is tge command to initiate the mpi compilation on the terminal, because I installed it and typed `msmpi` but the command wasn't recognized.